# How do I unregister mouse listener of JPanel

Tags: java, swing, panel, mouselistener

I have two JButtons and a JPanel.
How could I remove a registered mouselistener on JPanel if the Code for registering the mouse listener is as follows. On the click of one JButton this mouselistener is registered and now on the click of other JButton I want to remove the registered mouse listener.
If I write something like this on the click of Second JButton.

```
          pnlImagePanel.removeMouseListener();
```

But in above line the removeMouseListener() method requires listener object and I dont have class which has implemented the mouse listener. I have done following kind of coding for registering listener and also written the code in it self.

So please guide me friends How could I unregister the mouselistener.

Here is some part of the code.

```
           import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
           import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
           import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;

           Class abc{

                   pnlImagePanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
                System.out.println("Mouse Pressed");
                startingX = evt.getX();
                startingY = evt.getY();
                System.out.println(Startingx);
                System.out.println(StartingY);
            }
        });

             }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating anonymous `MouseListener`, create an object of a class which implements `MouseListener` class and then add it to the `JPanel` for listening. while removing, pass the created `MouseListener` object to the `removeMouseListener()` function.

Comment: Thank You! for your reply. I have the same thought but actually I want to know the way how to unregister the mouselistener which is registered in above way because I have big code. And it will be very tedious to manage the code by writing the another class. So put the idea of writing the another class which implements mouselistener optional

Comment: ok, I'll write the code and post it here in a while, takes some time

Comment: Thank You Friend! I will wait for your reply. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete code

See if this works for you

```
package testapplications;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author sunil
 */
public class ButtonRegistrationTest extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
    private javax.swing.JPanel panel;
    private javax.swing.JButton register;
    private javax.swing.JButton unregister;

    /** Creates new form ButtonRegistration */
    public ButtonRegistrationTest()
    {
        initComponents();
        PanelMouseListener listener = new PanelMouseListener();
        register.addActionListener(new RegisterMouseListener(listener));
        unregister.addActionListener(new UnRegisterMouseListener(listener));
    }

    private class PanelMouseListener extends MouseAdapter
    {
        PanelMouseListener()
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Clicked");
        }
    }

    private class RegisterMouseListener implements ActionListener
    {
        PanelMouseListener listener;
        RegisterMouseListener(PanelMouseListener listener)
        {
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            panel.addMouseListener(listener);
        }
    }

    private class UnRegisterMouseListener implements ActionListener
    {
        PanelMouseListener listener;

        public UnRegisterMouseListener(PanelMouseListener listener)
        {
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            panel.removeMouseListener(listener);
        }
    }


    private void initComponents() {

        panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        register = new javax.swing.JButton();
        unregister = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel.setName("panel"); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout panelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel);
        panel.setLayout(panelLayout);
        panelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 196, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        panelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 173, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        register.setText("Register");
        register.setName("register"); // NOI18N

        unregister.setText("Unregister");
        unregister.setName("unregister"); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 91, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(register, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(unregister, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(27, 27, 27))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                        .addComponent(register)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(unregister)))
                .addContainerGap(127, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new ButtonRegistration().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can remove all the mouseListeners from a component like below.

```
MouseListener[] mouseListeners = component.getMouseListeners();
for (MouseListener mouseListener : mouseListeners) {
    component.removeMouseListener(mouseListener);
}
```

Hope this helps.